# Reducer not holding the server response object - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to learn react and got an issue in redux.

The code is as follows.

```
import * as postActions from '../../redux/actions/postActions';

class PostForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    this.props.getBooks()
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Create Post</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <input required type="text" ref={(input)=>this.getTitle = input} 
        placeholder="Enter Post Title"/>
       <br /><br />
       <textarea required rows="5" ref={(input)=>this.getMessage = input} cols="28" 
        placeholder="Enter Post" />
       <br /><br />
       <button>Post</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  ...state.books,
}),{
  ...postActions,
})(PostForm);
```

As you can see, when the form is submitted, this.props.getBooks() action is called.
The action is defined as follows.

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
export function getBooks(obj={}) {
  const api = types.API_URL_BOOKS;
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
      type: types.ACTION_BOOK_LIST,
      promise: client => client.get(api).then((data) => {
        return data;
      }),
    });
  };
}
```

I am using axios for making api calls. The issue is that I am not getting the server response in reducer. The reducer is as follows.

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
export default function reducer(state = {}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case types.ACTION_BOOK_LIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        books : action.result.data.response.books
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

On debugging, i found that the action is having only the following

```
{type: "BOOK_LIST"}
```

After that, in the apiMiddlewareCreator (which is defined in clientMiddleware.js), i am getting the server response

```
function apiMiddlewareCreator(client) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, client);
    }

    const { promise, type, hideLoader, ...rest } = action;

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action);
    }

    next({ ...rest, type: `${type}` });

    const actionPromise = promise(client);

    actionPromise
      .then(result => {
        debugger
        if(result.data.success === false) throw result.data.message;


        if (result && result.data && result.data.response) {



          switch(action.type) {

            default:
                //nothing
          }
        }

        return next({ ...rest, result, type: `${type}_SUCCESS`, originalType: type })
      })

    return actionPromise;
  };
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
//import { routerReducer as routing } from 'react-router-redux';

import postReducer from './postReducer';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  // routing,
  books: postReducer,
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  return appReducer(state, action)
};

export default rootReducer;
```

actionTypes.js

```
export const ACTION_BOOK_LIST = 'BOOK_LIST';
```

> I need the data to be available in the reducer. That is,  action.result.data.response.books should contain the response from server.

I am not sure on how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to type: "BOOK_LIST" or types.ACTION_BOOK_LIST ?

Comment: types.ACTION_BOOK_LIST is already defined as BOOK_LIST. Please see the edits made in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're dispatching the action before the promise is resolved.

Only dispatch the action once the promise has been resolved, e.g:

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
export function getBooks(obj={}) {
  const api = types.API_URL_BOOKS;
  return dispatch => {
    client.get(api).then(data => {
      dispatch({
        type: types.ACTION_BOOK_LIST,
        books: data.response.books
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Your reducer will need to be updated to:

```
case types.ACTION_BOOK_LIST:
  return { ...state,
    books: action.books
  };
```